# How to pass variable from php file to ajax using json?

Tags: php, ajax

I can't seem to get the variable to ajax success function. (there is only one variable and nothing more)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var last_msg_id = $(this).attr("id");

$.ajax({//Make the Ajax Request
type: "POST",
url: "moredivid.php",
datatype: 'json',
data: "lastmsg="+ last_msg_id, 
success: function(data){//html = the server response html code
$('a.load_more').attr('id',data.msg_id);//Loading id during the Ajax Request
}
});
```

**PHP**

```
    if(isset($_POST['lastmsg']))
{
$lastmsg=$_POST['lastmsg'];
$msg_id="blah";
$msg_id=array("msg_id" => $msg_id);
echo json_encode($msg_id);
}
```

when I output(alert) only 'data' instead of 'data.msg_id' I get {"msg_id":"blah"} and the div id becomes

`id="{"msg_id":"blah"}".`

with the space in front.
 Output of  data.msg_id gives undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just type the wrong properties. Just change from

```
url: "moredivid.php",
datatype: 'json',
data: "lastmsg="+ last_msg_id,
```

to

```
url: "moredivid.php",
dataType: 'json',
data: "lastmsg="+ last_msg_id,
```

Comment: You're welcome. That's one of the hardest bug to find out. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP script, you can set the header as JSON using (if you're not interested in using the dataType parameter each time):

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

JQuery will automatically pick up on this header during the Ajax request.